# Strang flash behaver on AVCaptureDeviceInput

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I use this code to get flash working on the video that i recorded

```
NSError *error = nil;
// Create the session

AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

// Configure the session to produce lower resolution video frames, if your

// processing algorithm can cope. We'll specify medium quality for the

// chosen device.

session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;


// Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice

                           defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

// Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.

AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device

                                                                    error:&error];

[session addInput:input];


// Create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the session

AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init] ;

[session addOutput:output];


// Configure your output.

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);

[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

// Specify the pixel format

output.videoSettings =

[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:

 [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

                            forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];

[output setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];


// If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 15 fps, set

//turn flash on
[session beginConfiguration];
BOOL lockAcquired = [device lockForConfiguration:&error];

if (!lockAcquired) {
    // log err and handle...
} else {
    if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
}
[device unlockForConfiguration];
[session commitConfiguration];

// Start the session running to start the flow of data
[session startRunning];
```

but there is an strange behavior when recording start , the flash turn on then turn off for less a second then permanently stay on , **Did anyone know why and how i solve it ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try making `AVCaptureSession *session` and `AVCaptureDeviceInput *input` member variables of your class. They need to survive function scope

Comment: didn't change anything , still have the same start behavior